# Apple Development Xamarin.Forms: ERROR ITMS-90163 When Delivering App to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.forms

So I created an iOS app in Xamarin.Forms and I want to send it to TestFlight to send for certain people to test. I am using the application Transporter to send the ipa file to TestFlight. The first time I did it, it was successfully sent however in TestFlight it was just hanging on processing forever, I got an email saying:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "My App Name" 1.3 (1.3). Please correct the following issues, then
> upload again.

with this included:

> ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears
> to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
> signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment'
> entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
> make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
> Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
> Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment'
> entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment
> entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is
> intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications
> in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the
> entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

So in my app in Entitlements.plist I enabled Push Notifications. And in https://developer.apple.com/ I enabled Push Notifications in my Identifiers which is used for my profile. I also add Application Identifier in Entitlements.plist with the value of TEAMID.com.myorganization.MyApp and now I get this error when trying to deliver the app to TestFlight:

> ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements
> in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained
> in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not
> included in the provisioning profile: 'aps-environment'

What does this error mean and how to do I fix it? It seems to me like I need to include the Application Identifier to my provisioning profile and I have no idea how to do that, can anyone help, I have been stuck on this for days and none of the solutions out there havent worked for me.

Thanks,

Comment: show the contents of `Entitlements.plist`.  Mine is simply some XML header stuff, then nodes `<plist>` and `<dict>`. With a single key `aps-environment` having value `development`. Everything else is in my `Info.plist`.

Comment: It sounds like you have updated the provisioning profile on the developer website but this hasn't been downloaded to xcode, so the new entitlement isn't in the embedded provisioning profile. Are you using automatic signing managed by Xcode? If not you will need to manually download the profile and install it into your project by dragging it into Xcode

Comment: I solved this problem by just removing all my indentifiers, profiles and certificates and started from scratch

Comment: New problem though, ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.